# How can I order rows returned by the RETURNING clause of a DML statement?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I am using this statement to get all the rows ordered by timestamp in ascending order

```
DELETE FROM @tableName
        WHERE id = ANY (
            SELECT id
            FROM @tableName
            WHERE source = :p1 AND target = :p2 @readCondition
            ORDER BY createddate
            LIMIT @limit
            FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
        )
        RETURNING *;
```

And I am getting these results :

```
"MessageType":"AssignmentChange.v1","CreatedDate":"2019-12-05T10:55:22.230886"

"MessageType":"AssignmentChange.v1","CreatedDate":"2019-12-05T10:55:22.279604"

"MessageType":"AssignmentChange.v1","CreatedDate":"2019-12-05T10:55:22.276191"
"MessageType":"AssignmentChange.v1","CreatedDate":"2019-12-05T10:55:22.202338"
```

As you can see they are not sorted by `createdate`. Is there a way to sort rows from the `RETURNING` clause?

Answer (score 10):

You need to apply an ORDER BY to the result. To do that, put the DELETE statement into a common table expression. Then you can apply an ORDER BY when you select from it

```
with deleted as (
  DELETE FROM @tableName
  WHERE id = ANY (
        SELECT id
        FROM @tableName
        WHERE source = :p1 AND target = :p2 @readCondition
        ORDER BY createddate
        LIMIT @limit
        FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)
  RETURNING *
)
select *
from deleted 
order by createddate;
```